# Lua navigation in corona

Tags: navigation, lua, coronasdk

I have a level1.lua standalone and working program. but when I want to navigate into it using `gotoScene()`, it doesn't play!

```
local storyboard = require "storyboard"
local scene = storyboard.newScene("level1")

local function level1_pressed()
    storyboard.gotoScene( "level1", "fade" ,40 )
    print("level1 should start")
    return true
end

local level1 = display.newText( "level1",20 ,20,font, 40 )
level1:setTextColor(math.random( 50, 200 ),math.random( 50, 200 ),math.random( 50, 200 ))

level1:addEventListener( "touch", level1_pressed )
```

this is my main.lua.
the "level1 should start" string is printed properly on th terminal, but it does not start!
what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the storyboard documentation available at http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/storyboard/gotoScene.html, your syntax for storyboard.gotoScene() was incorrect

```
    local storyboard = require "storyboard"
    local scene = storyboard.newScene("level1")

    local options = {
        effect = "fade",
        time = 40
    }

    local function level1_pressed()
            storyboard.gotoScene( "level1", options)
            print("level1 should start")
            return true
    end

    local level1 = display.newText( "level1",20 ,20,font, 40 )
    level1:setTextColor(math.random( 50, 200 ),math.random( 50, 200 ),math.random( 50, 200 ))

    level1:addEventListener( "touch", level1_pressed )
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you read [documentation](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/storyboard/index.html)? level1.lua should contain something like [this](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/storyboard/index.html#scene-template). Also check out storyboard tutorials from [that](http://www.coronalabs.com/resources/tutorials/user-interface-scenes-and-widgets/) page.